# Unable to identify the path of VC++

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I have downloaded the microsoft visual C++,In control panel I can see the software download but unable to find the location it got installed I uninstalled it many ways and default also I set the location but I see there are no files in it.

I installed that software from the following link.

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010
```

My system configurations

Windows 7
64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Unless otherwise specified during install: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0`

Comment: I specified the path manually but I found there are no files in it.

Comment: Search the whole disk for files named "lib.exe, link.exe, nmake.exe"

Comment: I did but the search went into vain.........

Comment: Then I guess your installation failed.

Comment: I dont think so I got the finish tab and also to view the log after successfull installation

Comment: actually I need namke for 64 bit so in that process I am downloading the SDK

Answer (score 0):

Click 'Start'. Type 'Visual Studio' in the 'Search Programs and files' textbox at the bottom and wait. Results should appear where the start menu items were. RIGHT click on Visual Studio and click 'Properties. It will show the location under the 'General' tab and under the 'Shortcut' tab under 'Target'